# Unable to Make Template Based C++ Code Compile: Needed typename before Class

Tags: c++, templates

```
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

template<int x>
class MyClass{
    typedef Matrix<float,x,x> MyMatrix;
    MyClass();
    MyMatrix getMatrix();
};

template<int x>
MyClass<x>::MyClass(){
    int y =  x+1;
    MyMatrix m;
    MyClass::MyMatrix mx;
}

template<int x>
MyClass<int x>::MyMatrix getMatrix(){
    MyMatrix m;
    return m;
}
```

I have the following code. Unfortuantely, the last decalration cannot compile (getMatrix) and I get an error saying that I need a typename before MyCLass::MyMatrix because MyClass is a dependant scope

Changed it to :

```
template<int x>
typename MyClass<x>::MyMatrix MyClass<x>::getMatrix(){
    MyClass<x>::MyMatrix mx;
    return mx;
}
```

It is still not compiling and giving the same error. Also made them public

Comment: What's really unclear about the error message? Just write `typename MyClass<int x>::MyMatrix getMatrix(){`.

Comment: Why am i getting downvoted. This is a legit question

Comment: You miss to provide a [MCVE] including verbatim error messages, also it lacks research efforts obviously.

Comment: i did what you said..but now it says MyMatrix is not declared. I tried doing MyClass<x>::MyMatrix m; but it also throws an error saying needed typename before MyClass<x> etc.

Comment: Make the declaration `public`

Comment: I just tried that, get the exact same error again

Comment: okay, i think the only way is to write everything within the class itself, and not have my delclarations

Comment: Prefix you outside class function definitions with `MyClass<int x>::`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors in your code. Let's fix them one by one:

```
template<int x>
MyClass<x>::MyClass(){
    int y = x + 1;
    MyMatrix m;
    MyClass::MyMatrix mx;
}
```

Here it's really hard to even understand what you are trying to do here. Why is there `y`? And why are you trying to use the same class differently? Here's what it look like when fixed:

```
template<int x>
MyClass<x>::MyClass(){
    MyMatrix m;
    MyMatrix mx;
}
```

Both `MyMatrix` refers to the same one, the one you declared in `MyClass`.

---

Now, this piece of code:

```
template<int x>
MyClass<int x>::MyMatrix getMatrix(){
    MyMatrix m;
    return m;
}
```

The syntax is wrong here. The solution how to fix this is simply by looking at your code just above, and tell the what the compiler told you to do:

```
template<int x>
//               v----- Here!
typename MyClass<x>::MyMatrix getMatrix(){
//                   ^--- Dependent name here. Matrix is a type that depends
//                        on the parameter `x`. You must put typename to
//                        tell the compiler that it's a type
    MyMatrix m;
    return m;
}
```

Why would you specify the type of a variable when you use it?

I see no other problems.